# Javascript/jquery: passing outer 'this' to .each() while preserving the internal 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have the following code:

```
FootnoteCollection.prototype.positionWideFootnotes = function() {
    var that = this;
    this.$footnoteCollection.find('.footnote').each(function() {
        var $footnote = $(this);
        var minFootnoteOffset = that.options.footnoteUpperMargin;
    });
};
```

And it works (note: code has been simplified for clarity) but I would like to know if this is the accepted way of passing `this` around and if there are any alternatives.

Thanks!

EDIT: tried to make the question more of a question.

ONE FURTHER EDIT: I wasn't asking about the variable name `that` specifically. I wanted to know if `var anything = this` was the accepted way of passing `this` (or portions of `this`, like `this.options`).

Comment: 'bugging you' is not a programmatic issue. A lot of people use var that = this;

Comment: Why not declare `var minFootnoteOffset = this.options.footnoteUpperMargin;` on the outside?

Comment: What's wrong with `var that = this`? That's how you do it. `this` will be something else in the `.each` function. If it bothers you that much, try `var self = this`. Or `var foo = this`. Or `var bar = this`

Comment: I remember using var that = this; today itself on my day job!

Comment: As I mentioned, the code has been simplified quite a bit. `this.options` contains quite a few settings, so I'd have to redeclare all of them. Which would be really messy and make me sad.

Comment: So go with `var options = this.options`. Or if you need other stuff in `this`, just use a variable name that describes what `this` actually is at that point. Something like `var thisFootnoteCollection = this`. Then it'll be a lot easier to see what your `thisFootnoteCollection` is in the `.each` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `var that = this` is a pretty common idiom in Javascript. If it bothers you, you could make your code more readable my using a more descriptive variable name that `that`. Presumably, you know that `this` is (or should be) a `FootnoteCollection` at that point in the code, so why not:

```
FootnoteCollection.prototype.positionWideFootnotes = function() {
    var thisFootnoteCollection = this;
    this.$footnoteCollection.find('.footnote').each(function() {
        var $footnote = $(this);
        var minFootnoteOffset = thisFootnoteCollection.options.footnoteUpperMargin;
    });
};
```

Or, if you only need the options part:

```
FootnoteCollection.prototype.positionWideFootnotes = function() {
    var options = this.options;
    this.$footnoteCollection.find('.footnote').each(function() {
        var $footnote = $(this);
        var minFootnoteOffset = options.footnoteUpperMargin;
    });
};
```

I'd also argue that your code would be more readable if you didn't use `this` in the `.each` callback and instead used the arguments passed to `.each`:

```
FootnoteCollection.prototype.positionWideFootnotes = function() {
    var options = this.options;
    this.$footnoteCollection.find('.footnote').each(function(idx, value) {
        var $footnote = $(value);
        var minFootnoteOffset = options.footnoteUpperMargin;
    });
};
```

Because now there is no confusion as to what `this` is actually referring to.

Comment: Good idea on the `function(idx, value)` change.